# Record actual piano from Keyboard CASIO CTK-3200 to PC

Tags: audio-recording, recording, keyboard

I need to record actual sound of whatever I am playing on my keyboard (CASIO CTK-3200) on my PC.

I've looked up the Web for a place I could buy a USB interface cable or any other medium that would channel the output from the keyboard into a PC. I couldn't be sure of the solutions (No knowledge).

I've also looked in local stores. No luck there either.

Could you please help me if you know where I could find one?

Also, I live in **India** and the locals don't use the same vocabulary for the items that I found on internet e.g. Alesis LineLink, perhaps. My keyboard does have a USB interface but the USB port is a bit smaller in size than the usual USB ports (I guess this would be for the MIDI signal transmission, which is not a point of discussion here).

The terminals present on my casio are as follows:
HEADPHONES/OUTPUT (standard stereo jack)
SUSTAIN/DAMPER
AUDIO IN
USB: type B*
EXTERNAL POWER (9.5V DC)
* USB cable (A-B type) required to use USB terminal for computer connection.

Source: http://www.casio-intl.com/asia-mea/en/emi/standard/ctk3200/spec/

So I believe I'd be channeling out the output from the Headphones channel to the PC.

With this information now, could you please help me of the best and inexpensive solutions (if I need to buy anything)? I highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You gonna need an audio interface (unless you got decent sound card allready, but most of them are multimedia purposed, and not the best solution for recording of any kind). Your keyboard does not support USB recording, so You'll need to use lineout jack. After getting the audio interface, you will need to just plug the instrument in and that's that connection-wise. 
If you're looking for a cheap solution with mediocre sound quality, chceck out Behringer cheapest stuff. It will be allright for notepading the ideas, but not for any even half-serious things. If you'd like quality to be a tad better, try this http://www.musicradar.com/news/tech/13-of-the-best-budget-usb-audio-interfaces-570850/14. It will set you back around 80 quid, but it's worth it.

Comment: Hi @roonroon, Thanks for the advice but I'd need to research how these things work and are they even available here in india. Also, these instruments are not that cheap. This might be noob, but do you think if there could be a solution wherein I could connect my headphone output to the mic in of my laptop directly. Would that help (if possible)?

Comment: Nothing to research realy - interface like the ones i mentioned aren't instruments - they are usb 'cards'. External inputs and outputs with own proccessing power. The only difference between 'mic in your laptop' technical-wise is it's far better quality (even the really cheap ones) and it's external. Principal is the same. As far as price goes - You need to be prepared to pay at least around 40 GPB for cheapest, lowest quality gear.
You could in theory connect keys to  'mic in your laptop', but the quality will be nonexistent & signal/noise ratio will kill. Also,it may burn your soundcard.